# Make "Remove from Folder" default or shortcut

Tags: lotus-notes

Is there any way to make doing a "Remove from Folder" easier other than a bunch of clicking?  I really want that to be the default for the Delete key because I like to generally Archive everything for later search and keep my Inbox clean (zero).  Or some shortcut?  Or some other approach?  Anything would help, I'm so new to Lotus and I hate it already!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just file the message into a folder?  That removes it from the inbox.  You want to do it in one click?  Install SwiftFile.  That is a free add-on from IBM that gives 3 hotlinks at the top of the message to file the message into a folder.  The 3 folders are guesses based on your filing habits for similar messages.  The software learns from your filing habits and improves its guesses over time, though it is very good at it from the start.  You want more tips on handling your inbox and sent folders, see my blog at http://blog.thenotesguyinseattle.com

Comment: Thanks for the SwiftFile recommendation.  While it's not ideal, I think it will work just fine.  I've created an "Archive" folder for things I don't want to delete but want to be able to find via search later.

Answer (score 0):

To take this old answer a step further.  Without the use of anything third party, you can create a custom button in Notes, with the following as the code behind it:

```
@Command([FolderDocuments];"Completed";"1")
```

This new button, will take any item selected in lotus notes, and move it to the specified folder.  Just remember to Change 'Completed' to the name of the folder you would like to use.